# Need advice on storing a massive 3d array

Tags: mysql, multidimensional-array

I am working with a very large 3d byte array.
Currently (for testing) I have been working with it in memory anywhere from 256, 32, 256 to 3200, 256, 3200 and simply generating it at runtime. This usually takes 45~ seconds at the longest.
Now I would like to start storing the data, as I would like to work with a larger array and 3200x256x3200 is close to the memory limit I am working with.  I was hoping to do it in mysql.
I have a table and all works, but writing the data takes too long for my purposes even using a smaller array.
I currently have a for loop writing each line into the db.
What would a more efficient, ie faster, way to do it? Or should I give up on the mysql idea and look for another method? And if so any links to the methodology would be apreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Do you need it in a database? A memory mapped file (that you generate once and use again and again) might make more sense.

Comment: I don't need it in a db. I just store everything else there. I'm at work right now but I'll try writing multiple rows when I get home and if that doesn't increase the speed dramatically I'll research memory maps.

Answer (score 0):

Writing line-by-line will take forever, but you can insert multiple rows with a single INSERT statement.

```
INSERT MyTable (ColA, ColB, ColC) VALUES (1,2,3),(,4,5,6),(7,8,9)...
```

The limit is on the size of query MySQL will accept. By default this is 1Mb, but you can make it larger if necessary

The Mysql reference is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)